# How to edit number in column i-th of row n-th with bash shell

Tags: awk

I have a data file like this:

```
1  7.1  3.506678
2  4.7  4.700778
3  5.9  5.901760
4  8.2  4.397694
.....
```

I would like to replace the third column of several lines, for example, 2nd and 3rd line with the same number. Can anyone suggest a solution?

```
for i in 2 3;
do
    awk -v line="$i" 'NR==line {gsub(/4\.7/, "2\.3", $3)} 1'
done
```

Expected Output

```
1  7.1  3.506678
2  4.7  2.300778 #changed
3  5.9  2.301760 #changed
4  8.2  4.397694
```

Comment: _3rd and 4th line_ [2nd and 3rd] _with the same number_ [in fields `$2`and `$3`] assumed on the expected output: `awk 'BEGIN{OFS="  "}substr($3,1,3)==$2{sub(/^.../,"2.3",$3)}1' file`

Comment: I am sorry that I do not obtain the result I expect. Could you please comment sth more?

Comment: Don't say `I want to change the 3rd and 4th lines` and then show an example changing the 2nd and 3rd lines - make your requirements and example consistent with each other to make it as easy as possible for us to help you, not as hard.

Answer (score 1):

First create a backup of your input file just in case.

Then maybe this loop could work?

```
for i in 3 4; do
   awk -v row="$i" -v column=3 -v new_string="some_value" 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}NR==row{sub(/.*/,new_string,$column)} 1' stack.tsv > out.tsv
   cp out.tsv stack.tsv
done
```

**INPUT:**

```
cat stack.tsv
1   7.1 3
2   4.7 4
3   5.9 5
4   8.2 4
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
cat stack.tsv
1   7.1 3
2   4.7 4
3   5.9 some_value
4   8.2 some_value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="  "; a[2]; a[3]} NR in a{sub(/.../,2.3,$3)} 1' file
1  7.1  3.506678
2  4.7  2.300778
3  5.9  2.301760
4  8.2  4.397694
```

or in general for many lines:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{split("2 3",tmp); for (i in tmp) a[tmp[i]]; FS=OFS="  "} NR in a{sub(/.../,2.3,$3)} 1' file
1  7.1  3.506678
2  4.7  2.300778
3  5.9  2.301760
4  8.2  4.397694
```

Answer (score 1):

Repeatedly running Awk on the same file is inelegant, slow, and somewhat brittle. Refactor your script to perform all the changes in one go.

```
awk -v lines=3:4 'BEGIN { i = split(lines, n, ":"); for(j=1; j<=i; ++j) line[n[j]]++ }
  FNR in line { sub(/^[0-9]\.[0-9]/, "2\.3", $3)} 1' file >newfile
```

Awk will mangle (or, well, normalize) the spacing on the lines it modifies; if this is a significant problem, there are ways to preserve the original spacing, but that will complicate the solution.